# Preposions following Ph.d: 'Ph.d in' or 'Ph.d on'

Tags: prepositions

I'm confused using a preposition after the word PhD. Say,

> PhD ***on*** Archaeology 
>  PhD ***in*** Archaeology

I have seen both "in" and "on" follwoing PhD Is there any difference?

Answer (score 4):

PhD or DPhil [UK] or Ph.D.[US]

You have a PhD ***in*** a subject.

You study for it ***at*** a university.

You work ***on*** a thesis, but your resulting doctorate is ***in*** that topic.

Refs: [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/phd), [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/phd)

Answer (score 2):

Both can be right. You do a PhD *in* a discipline. Eg a PhD in Engineering.

More colloquially, a PhD concerns a rather narrow particular topic. In this case you might say "I did my PhD on the psychoneurolinguistic effects of conjunction confusion." The "on" (=concerning) in this case refers not just to the thesis, but the research and the advancement of the communal state of knowledge that is required for a PhD.

Due to the breadth of a field and the narrowness of a PhD, having a PhD does not necessarily make you an expert at that field but rather an expert *in* areas within that field.

Answer (score -3):

Both might be in practice but my horse sense says that 'on' is *more* appropriate. Why? Because, the PhD is **on** some topic. So, *'PhD on molecular biology,'* is more frequent than *'PhD in molecular biology.'*

On the other hand, if you are talking about some university or country, *at/in* may go. Say, *PhD in the UK,* or maybe, *'PhD at Brisbane University.*

See the fun, if I say *PhD **on** the UK* would mean that I'm pursuing PhD on the country UK!